# lay odds against someone

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "lay odds against someone" mean? I've only heard of "lay odds against an event."

> Slight revisions have been made to DeLay's fantasy – Doggett moved across town and won the Dem nomination in CD 25 and will almost certainly stay in D.C., and Edwards decided to fight for the new CD 17 against state Rep. (and rabid right-winger) Arlene Wohlgemuth. But the conventional wisdom says things are mostly on track for DeLay: CD 10's Republican nomination went to Austinite Michael McCaul, a committed George W. Bush foot soldier, and a betting man wouldn't **lay odds against him**, Carter, or Lamar Smith.

Comment: A betting man wouldn't bet against him, Carter or Lamar Smith **winning**. In other words, a gambler wouldn't put money on them losing. Any (or all) of those three people might win.

Answer (score 1):

*a betting man wouldn't lay odds against him, Carter, or Lamar Smith* means these three candidates have high chance of winning, as @Old Brixtonian has commented.

[lay odds](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay-odds)

> make a bet on terms favorable to the other party